# Get label of UIButtons to line up regardless of image size

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have several buttons I'm adding to a view controller that each have different images and a label.

I want the labels of the buttons to be aligned by their leading edge, and preferably have the images be aligned by vertical center, though I'll settle just for the labels to be aligned.

Is this possible with settings on the UIButton itself? Or would I be better off just making a custom view with an image and label?

Here's a crude example of what I mean. The green is the button, red is the image.

Basically, I want to define a max size for the image, with the image centered, and the label would always be up against this set size so the are aligned.

I had achieved this via storyboard by setting custom insets on each button to get the alignment, but am re-creating the View Controller to get around some limitations due to the Reveal View Controller. This is the "rear view", our menu. We want to be able to more dynamically choose which view controller to start out as the front view controller, which, using storyboards, doesn't seem feasible. You have to explicitly set which will be the front view.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's easier implemented using tableView with custom cell. You can customize the cell to make it have 'button' feel when tapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the text in buttons with different size images…

1. Set all your buttons' `contentHorizontalAlignment = .left`
2. Calculate the width of the widest image…

`let maxWidth = [button1, button2, button3].map({$0!.imageView!.image!.size.width}).max()!`

3. To move all content to the right (so set the space to the left of the image), set the buttons' `contentEdgeInsets.left`. To move the text further to the right (setting the space between the image and the text), set the buttons' `titleEdgeInsets.left`

Like this…

```
let minInset: CGFloat = 8 // largest image has inset of 8 to left and right
for button in [button1, button2, button3] {

    let imageWidth = button!.imageView!.image!.size.width
    let inset = (maxWidth + (minInset * 2) - imageWidth) / 2

    button?.contentEdgeInsets.left = inset
    button?.titleEdgeInsets.left = inset
}
```

and you should end up with…

[image]

Comment: Above and beyond what I could have asked for! I was hoping there would be an attribute I could set but you've managed to just do all the calculations per button in a very neat manner. I was readying to attempt something like this today but wasn't expecting it to come out nearly this clean. Thanks for the map example, too, that's far cleaner than the loop I would have done to find the max.